# How to remove opacity in element from react dnd?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, react-dnd

When I drag an item from react-dnd, the element which i'm dragging goes almost 100% opacity, I want to make him more visible, how can I do it?

In this image bellow, I have the upper element (the one i'm dragging), and the bottom which is in "movement", he almost disappear with the opacity:

[image]

This is the div which creates the card, i've made with tailwind:

```
className={`p-3 flex flex-col gap-2 shadow-xl rounded-lg m-2 cursor-grab bg-base-200`}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wondering if this example would work?
You can remove the opacity from the element being dragged by using the collect function to pass in the `isDragging` prop to your component.

Then you can use the `isDragging` prop to conditionally apply the opacity style to your element.

```
const YourComponent = (props) => {
  const { isDragging } = props;
  const opacity = isDragging ? 0 : 1;

  return <div style={{ opacity: opacity }}>...</div>
}

export default DragSource(
  ItemTypes.YOUR_ITEM_TYPE,
  {
    beginDrag(props) {
      //...
    },
    endDrag(props, monitor) {
      const item = monitor.getItem();
      const dropResult = monitor.getDropResult();
      //...
    },
    collect: (connect, monitor) => ({
      isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
    }),
  },
  (connect, monitor) => ({
    connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(),
    isDragging: monitor.isDragging(),
  }),
)(YourComponent);
```

Comment: in this case you are talking about the element which is being dragged, i'm trying to change the opacity of the element when I move him, his "clone".